# Cross-platform Mac/Linux/PC no longer working in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

Since a PC update to 1.0.1.501, this seems to have broken cross platform play between Mac/Linux versions and PC versions of the game.

Aspyr Media - the developers of the Mac/Linux version of Civ 6 - said on [twitter on 29th May that](https://twitter.com/AspyrMedia/status/1266385380120711169):

> Maya & Gran Colombia Pack is available now

This suggests an update to be inline with the Windows version, yet the bug still persists.

When playing on the "Internet" option, Mac/Linux users are presented with the error: "Version Mismatch", while playing on "Unified PC Play", an unspecified error occurs when connecting

Does anyone know if there is a workaround to force Civilization to not check the version since they are running the same build (to my knowledge)?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the macOS version of Civ is always several months behind the Windows version, meaning crossplay often breaks for long periods of time. You'd think companies would either push updates for all crossplay platforms simultaneously, or stop claiming to "support" crossplay when they can't properly support it.

Comment: @Nolonar that's bad if it's true. I'm looking at a possible workaround that involves the "ineedlegacyaccess" beta code in steam properties

Comment: I'm having same issue. However one of solutions is - move your friends to linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/gvotl1/mac_multiplayer_fix/) that worked for me (performing on my mac to play with windows users):

- Go to:

  - `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/Civ6.app/Contents/AspyrAssets/global/String/App.json` on Mac
  - `~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/aspyrassets/global/string/app.json` on Linux
- Change the following lines:

```
    "App.WinFileVersion" : "1.0.1.501",
    "App.WinProductVersion" : "1.0.1.501",
    "App.WinFileVersionStr" : "(504666)",
    "App.WinProductVersionStr" : "(504666)",
```

It goes without saying that this can lead to unexpected errors. (I didn't notice any.)

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Linux too. The JSON file is located at: `~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/aspyrassets/global/string/app.json`

Comment: This worked for my friend above on linux. I edited the solution for the linux version, yet to confirm it works on Mac, gonna test with my friend today but looks hopeful